# How can I get css class suggestion from a html file in my css file on VScode?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

suppose i have a html file like this:

```
//index.html

<div class="home__data">
<h1 class="home__title">Hi, I'am Alexa</h1>
<h3 class="home__subtitle">Frontend Developer</h3>
<p class="home__description">High level experience in web design, knowledge and producing quality work.</p>
<a href="#" class="button button--flex">
Contact Me <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

now i want to get suggestion of the ***css class*** of this  ***index.html*** file in  my css file on ***VSCODE***

you can think about ***css intelliSense on vscode*** .if we write css class attribute on my html file we get suggestion of class that are written in css file. I want something like this but i want get suggestion in my **css file** of class that are written in html file.

```
//style.css
```

***Is that possible?***

Comment: can you be more precise to explain your Question

Comment: I have edited . i think you will understand the problem now.

Comment: might be this can help you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

Comment: i have already used that. It gives suggestion on html file. But i want  suggestion of class on my css file like that extension.

Comment: How about this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion

Comment: btw i use neovim nowdays :)

Answer (score 4):

These are the extensions that solved the problem.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

These two extensions can add this functionality easily.